# Tab separated data is confused to tables when parsing pdf to text

Tags: pdf, layout, pdfminer

I am using `pdfMiner` to convert `pdf` to `txt`. When there are tabs, the data is read column wise instead of row wise. For example, the below snippet in a PDF:

```
titel1 : text1
title2:             text2
title title3:       text3
```

is converted to:

```
titel1 : text1
title2:            
title title3:       
text2
text3
```

How can I get it row by row like how they originally appeared in the original PDF?
P.S. I am using `pdf2txt.py`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issu. Try it with pdfplumer (https://pypi.org/project/pdfplumber/) this is built up on pdfMiner.

This Code worked perfectly fine for me:

```
def pdf2txt(path):
    with pdfplumber.open(path, laparams = {"detect_vertical": False}) as pdf:
        text=""
        for page in pdf.pages:
            text= text +"\n"+ page.extract_text()

    return text
```